# How to atomically update a counter shared between Docker instances

Tags: linux, performance, docker, shared-memory

I have a simple C++ service (API endpoint) that increases a counter every time the API is called. When the caller posts data to http://10.0.0.1/add the counter has to be incremented by 1 and return the value of the counter to the caller.

Things get more complicated when the service is getting dockerized. When two instances of the same service run the addition has to be done atomically, ie the counter value is stored in a database and each docker instance has to acquire a lock get the old value, add one, return to the caller and unlock.

When the instances are processes in the same Linux machine, we used shared memory to efficiently lock, read, write and unlock the shared data and the performance was accepted. However when we use dockers and a database the performance is low. The results are OK, however the performance is low.

What is the canonical way between instances of dockerized properties to perform operations like the one described above? Is there a "shared memory" feature for containerized processes?

Comment: Do you need an exact count of requests at all times? It may be easier to have each container track locally then have another process aggregate them occasionally (i.e. as Prometheus or Grafana metrics).

Comment: Exact count at all times, ie I cannot depend on "local" data. Let's assume that this counter is an update on a bank account, ie I cannot update the money periodically.

Comment: What you ask here is probably a simplified case. How should it behave at scale?

Comment: @ovanes, actually this is the problem. Several processes have to share a common source and should also synchronize on the value of the source. What is the optimal/canonical way to share the value in order to scale?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like for your case database is overhead. You just need some distribute lightweight key-value storage with shared key lock support. Here are some candidates:

- etcd (https://coreos.com/etcd)
- consul (https://www.consul.io, especially https://www.consul.io/docs/commands/lock.html)
- redis (http://redis.io)

Comment: consul.io depends on http communication between the process and the KV storage. This will introduce a latency, doesn't it?

Comment: In general yes comparing with shared memory and single host but in practice, latency is much lower than using a database.

Comment: Related to @Vyacheslav's idea, you could use [redis](https://store.docker.com/images/redis) container to store the data. Set-up a docker network and have each of the containers on the same network for easy access and service discovery.

Comment: Yeah, forgot about it but it also relatively lightweight. Added to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [`--ipc` option of `docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#ipc-settings---ipc) enables shared-memory access between containers:

> ### IPC settings (--ipc)
>
> `--ipc=""`  : Set the IPC mode for the container,
>
> `'container:<name|id>'`: reuses another container's IPC namespace
>
> `'host'`: use the host's IPC namespace inside the container
>
> By default, all containers have the IPC namespace enabled.
>
> IPC (POSIX/SysV IPC) namespace provides separation of named shared
> memory segments, semaphores and message queues.
>
> Shared memory segments are used to accelerate inter-process
> communication at memory speed, rather than through pipes or through
> the network stack. Shared memory is commonly used by databases and
> custom-built (typically C/OpenMPI, C++/using boost libraries) high
> performance applications for scientific computing and financial
> services industries. If these types of applications are broken into
> multiple containers, you might need to share the IPC mechanisms of the
> containers.

[This article](https://dzone.com/articles/docker-in-action-the-shared-memory-namespace) provides some demonstration of its usage.

Comment: Then the x86 instruction fetch and add could be used to increase the counter. You wont get faster than that

Comment: Does this imply that the docker images are on the same host (same kernel)?. Does it work if the docker containers live on different machines?

Comment: Shared memory works only for containers on the same machine. You can't avoid network access if you must synchronize containers running on different machines.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar problem, and decided to dig in it head on.

The only thing that goes fast is domain sockets. So i created a small c-program that listens on a domain socket, on a shared volume /sockets.

see a working concept on [test](https://gitlab.com/dgoo2308/test_domain_sockets) on gitlab.com.

`counter.c` does the job, listens on sockets/count.sock and
on receipt of a single char in a datagram:

- '+' : it will increase the count and return the count as an u_int64_t
- '0' : resets the count and return the 0 value as an u_int64_t
- '=' : returns the count as an u_int64_t, without increment
- '-' : decrement count with one and returns count as an u_int64_t

for concept testing:

- `counter --interval=1000000` => starts the counter
- `test_counter --repeats=100000 stress` => sents 100k request to the socket
- `test_counter reset` set's counter to 0
- `test_counter --quiet --strip result` returns the counter without `\n`
- `test_counter [count]` increments the counter and returns result.

2 docker containers are build: `count` & `test` [repo](https://gitlab.com/dgoo2308/test_domain_sockets/container_registry)

and to test, I used docker-compose.yml in a gitlab-runner:

```
my-test:
    image: dockregi.gioxa.com/dgoo2308/dockersocket:test
    links:
    - counter
    entrypoint:
    - /test_counter
    - --repeats=${REPEATS}
    - --timeout=200
    - stress
volumes:
- './sockets:/sockets'

counter:
    image: dockregi.gioxa.com/dgoo2308/dockersocket:count
    volumes:
    - './sockets:/sockets'
    entrypoint:
    - /counter
    - --start_delay=100
    - --interval=${TARGET}
```

to start test:

```
mkdir sockets
docker-compose pull --parallel
docker-compose up -d
docker-compose scale my-test=$SCALE
```

Concept Test Success full!!! see [test Job](https://gitlab.com/dgoo2308/test_domain_sockets/builds/16854914)

*cavecat:*

for client implementation, client socket cannot be bind as auto, but need to be given a name, see in test we use the hostname, mapped in the same /sockets volume.
Also they need to be different for each client.

Comment: Does this require that docker images are on the same host? Domain sockets imply that we are at the same "kermel"

Comment: Yes, it would require to be on the same host

Comment: This will not be the case in normal circumstances. In production containers will live in different hosts.